# ASP.net Reverse User GUID to UserName

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, membership

Struggling trying to find best way to reverse a GUID to username.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using the `SqlMembershipProvider`, use

```
var user = Membership.GetUser((object)yourGuid);
var userName = user.UserName;
```